# Fix/Absolute Position of Text Box in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to make the text box in fix position in a document, and is independent to text changes or movement in the document.

[image]

Even if I already wrap the text into `Tight` and checked `Fix Position on Page`, the text box still moves after one line movement of the word `March 2020`. How shall I give the text box, absolute position in the document?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following steps to have a check:

1. Select the text box and right click the edge to open "More Layout Options".
2. Choose "Position" tab, the vertical position would be the desired distance below Paragraph by default, you may change it to Margin. Then the box of "Move object with text check box" would be clear.

[image]

3. If needed, you may choose "Behind Text" instead of "Tight" in "Text Wrapping" tab, the following gif shows the result when I enter Enter key to move down "March 2020".

[image]